# Ordered categorical xlabel number - what to call xlabel

Tags: plotting, labels

Say I have 105 brand names from a store, and I know the average retrun percentage for the products of the different brands. .
For example:

`Brand = Nike, return_rate = 30%`

Then I order all these brands and simply put in an integer instead of the name (since I can't put all brands on the xlabel)

So now Nike is simply number 50:

`Brand = 50, return_rate = 30%`

The graph looks like this

[image]

I have no clue what to call the xlabel.. Would love your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not put any value on the xaxis ticks. I would title the x axis "Brands (ordered from lowest to highest return rate)". Though I am not sure what the plot is telling me. If it fits your story then great.

Comment: It's showing exactly what you write. I think it's a good idea removing the ticks! Ty!